# cakephp 3.x Sub select to get a count value

Tags: cakephp-3.0

after some research I created this find statement, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
   'count' => "SELECT COUNT(plans_trainings.id) FROM plans_trainings, trainings, projects WHERE plans_trainings.training_id = trainings.id AND projects.location_id = locations.id AND plans_trainings.project_id = projects.id"
);

public function trainingsPerLocationChartData(){
$this->loadModel('Locations');
$locationsDiagramData = $this->Locations->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'locations.id',
                'locations.description',
                'locations.count' /* virtuel field */
            )
        ));
```

The statement will look like this:

```
'sql' => 'SELECT locations.id AS `locations__id`, locations.description AS `locations__description`, locations.count AS `locations__count` FROM locations Locations'
```

The virtual field is not recognized at all.
What do I do wrong?

UPDATE:
I found out that I have to call it like this:

```
'count' => "(SELECT COUNT(plans_trainings.id) FROM plans_trainings, trainings, projects WHERE plans_trainings.training_id = trainings.id AND projects.location_id = locations.id AND plans_trainings.project_id = projects.id) AS `counter`"
```

I added () around the select.

```
$locationsDiagramData = $this->Locations->find('all')
            ->select(['locations.id', 'locations.description', $this->virtualFields['count']]);
```

But I still get a wrong sql syntax:

```
SELECT locations.id AS `locations__id`, locations.description AS `locations__description`, (SELECT COUNT(plans_trainings.id) FROM plans_trainings, trainings, projects WHERE plans_trainings.training_id = trainings.id AND projects.location_id = locations.id AND plans_trainings.project_id = projects.id) AS `counter` AS (SELECT COUNT(plans_trainings__id) FROM plans_trainings, trainings, projects WHERE plans_trainings FROM locations Locations
```

The "last" problem seem only this part after AS `counter`:

> AS (SELECT COUNT(plans_trainings__id) FROM plans_trainings, trainings,
>   projects WHERE plans_trainings

This is what the statement breaks!
Any ideas how to solve that?
If I run the statement in phpmyadmin and remove this mentioned part, the statement works fine and brings the right results!

UPDATE 2:
this is the plain statement:

```
select
                locations.id,
    locations.description,
    (
                               select
                                               count(plans_trainings.id)
                               from
                                               plans_trainings,
            trainings,
            projects
                               where
                                               plans_trainings.training_id = trainings.id
                                               and projects.location_id = locations.id
                                               and plans_trainings.project_id = projects.id
    ) as 'Anzahl'
from
                locations;
```

Comment: There are no virtual fields in CakePHP 3 anymore... use a proper [**subquery**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries) and pass it to [**`select()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in controller

```
$this->loadModel('Locations'); 
$this->loadModel('PlansTrainings'); 
$this->loadModel('Trainings'); 
$this->loadModel('Projects'); 
$sub_query=$this->PlansTrainings->find()->select(['cnt1'=>'count(PlansTrainings.id)'])->join([
        [
            'table' => 'trainings',
            'alias' => 'Trainings',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'PlansTrainings.training_id=Trainings.id',
        ],
        [
            'table' => 'projects',
            'alias' => 'Projects',
            'type' => 'INNER', //LEFT, RIGHT...
            'conditions' => ['Projects.location_id=PlansTrainings.id','PlansTrainings.project_id=Projects.id'],
        ],
]);
$locationsDiagramData = $this->Locations->find()->select(['id', 'description','count'=>$sub_query]);
```